# RN expo Standalone app using Authsession in LAN Environment, Possible?

Tags: react-native, authentication, oauth, expo

My standalone app need to be authorized by the OAuth provider in LAN environment. It works perfect in development because I can access the internet. However after I publish the app, AuthSession.getRedirectUrl() still redirecting the url to be https://auth.expo.io/@your-username/your-app-slug,is this correct? In the production, device only be used in LAN, no any connection from outside. Any possible way to get rid of auth.expo.io? Or any react native library do the same job but more customizable?

Thanks

```
//this redirectURL always return auth.expo.io/@name/slug
let redirectUrl = AuthSession.getRedirectUrl();
    let result = await AuthSession.startAsync({
      authUrl:
        `exampleurl` +
        `&client_id=${FB_APP_ID}` +
        `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl)}`,
    });
```

expecting redirect url be   "myapp://"  but result is "http://auth.expo.io/@myname/myapp

Comment: authsession can do these kind of customized stuff. Use browser instead.